# How do I fake tick lines in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a boring graph with a single value over time:

[image: sad, boring graph]

I'm displaying that alongside other more interesting specimens:

[image: slightly more exciting graph]

I'd like to mimic the horizontal tick lines on the top graph.
Is there a way to do this in D3?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a simple way. But the way you could do it is just loop through the y pos of the x axis and to y pos of the top of the y axis and create some data to pass through to D3 to create the lines for you ?

Comment: What's wrong with this: http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/adding-grid-lines-to-d3js-graph.html ?

Comment: It's hard to tell without any code, but my interpretation is that your data values' extent for the first chart is `[318,318]`, i.e. there is only a single constant value (min==max), right? You are then passing this *extent* to the axis' domain giving the above result. Setting `.domain([300,240])` might help. To get further help please provide a live demo.

Comment: Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fe3dmc0o/4/. Change var data to g1 or g2.